# Waiting for observable to finish - Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, observable

I'm using Angular and Firebase storage to upload images and I'm having the problem where my `urlImg` it's `undefined` when I try to print it in the `console.log` inside of the `tap`.

```
 this.snapshot = this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.storage
          .ref(path)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .subscribe(url => {
            this.urlImg = url; // with this you can use it in the html
          });
      }),
      tap(snap => {
        if (snap.bytesTransferred === snap.totalBytes) {
          // Update firestore on completion
          //Code to upload on completion
          console.log("url");
          console.log(this.urlImg);
        }
      })
    );
```

Comment: That `tap` will occur before the `finalize`, as `finalize` is the last thing that happens

Comment: @user184994 ohh i didn't that ! any suggestions? on how to fix this issue?

Comment: It depends what it is you're trying to do really. You can obviously access `this.urlImg` from within that `subscribe` if you need to?

Comment: I want to wait for the file to be uploaded, then get the url of the image in Firebase storage then upload to firestore the url from the image located in Firebase Storage @user184994

Comment: [typescript - wait for an observable/promise to finish, and return observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304160/typescript-wait-for-an-observable-promise-to-finish-and-return-observable)

Comment: [Wait for subscription to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162905/wait-for-subscription-to-complete)

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to take advantage of the completed section of subscribe. Then you can be sure that this.urlImg has a value.

```
.subscribe(
   url => this.urlImg = url,
   err => console.error('Request for URL failed: ' + err),
   () => {
      // operations when URL request is completed
   }
)
```