# How to delay an Angular7 pipe observable to run after 2 seconds

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angular7

I want to delay this pipe to return value only after 2 seconds.

What would be the idyllic way to delay such observable pipe.

```
export class StoragePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private afStorage: AngularFireStorage) { }
    transform(path: string): Observable<string> {
        if(path){
            return this.afStorage.ref(path).getDownloadURL();
       }

    }
}
```

I tried something like this  return `this.afStorage.ref(path).getDownloadURL().pipe(delay(2000));` 
That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I`m not sure you can do it, but there are many other ways to do what you want to do.
You can for instance just show what you want to show and after 2 secs (settimeout) run over all your array(what ever) and then transform it with your pipe.

Comment: What does `getDownloadURL()` return? Observable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413969/how-can-i-create-an-observable-with-a-delay

Comment: I don't think this is a best solution. See, the reason why I think this won't work is for the following. The time will be different based on the size of the file you are uploading to firebase storage. Sometimes it's almost instant, sometimes takes several seconds.

Comment: I asked a similar question before. I ran into the same issue..hope you find the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918032/waiting-for-observable-to-finish-angular

Comment: @AmitChigadani it returns an observable.

Comment: @AmitChigadani it does return an observable

Comment: have you tried ``throttleTime()`` ?

Comment: @CruelEngine yeah, I did.

Comment: @LearnToday that didn't work ?

Comment: @CruelEngine No, it didn't work. ``return this.afStorage.ref(path).getDownloadURL().pipe(throttleTime(5000));``

Comment: @LearnToday try this : ``return this.afStorage.ref(path).getDownloadURL().pipe(timer(5000));``

Comment: @CruelEngine Observable<number> ``timer`` is not assignable to .....

Comment: @LearnToday sorry was wrong in the implementation , you'll have to subscribe to the timer and then subscribe your observable . something like this : ``timer(5000).pipe( takeWhile(//make condition false here to stop emitting ), // do my operation));``

Comment: @LearnToday have created a stackblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fuazpy

Comment: Thanks @CruelEngine. I'll check that out!